# Perform Login and Register using Knex, Express and NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I want to build an application using Knex-MySQL, Express and NodeJS. I uploaded a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PBRsjtu73saUxlWaAxul?p=catalogue) for my code. I don't have frontend yet, I am using Postman.

Register works fine, but on login I get

```
{
    "status": "User not found"
}
```

or

```
{
    "message": "Missing credentials"
}
```

Which seems to be the problem? Why doesn't login see the user I inserted into db?

Comment: Why -1? I bothered you that much with my question? I gave all the explanations, nothing unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem and modified the function from `local.js` like this:

```
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
  function (username, password, done) {
    knex('user')
      .where('email', '=', username)
      .then((err, user) => {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
        }
        if (!user.isValid(password)) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      })
  }
));
```

`email` is not what passportjs is looking for, but `username` is.